# How to select time and date range with React DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using React Date Picker and I need to include time along with Date range for a single input. I didn't find any example from documentation how to implement this. Does DatePicker provide any functionality ?

the component is written as

after changing the date it throws err:
"TypeError: dateRange is not iterable"

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


function CustomDatePicker(props: any) {
  
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([null, null]);
  const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;
  return (
  <DatePicker
   selectsRange={true}
   startDate={startDate}
   endDate={endDate}
   timeInputLabel="Time:"
   onChange={(update: any) => {
   setDateRange(update);
   }}
   dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
   isClearable={true}
   showTimeSelect
   />
  );
}`

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

Comment: You have to add the prop ' showTimeSelect'  , the examples are given here : https://reactdatepicker.com/

Comment: I have added a snippet above@roma